# FSM problem vhdl AES encryption not entering in third state?

Tags: encryption, aes, vhdl

I had to code the encryption of AES using VHDL and it should compile to succeed the course!!!
I'm having some troubles , FSM isn't entering in the third state!

THIS is the code of FSM:

```
-- MOORE
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library LIB_RTL ;
library LIB_AES;
use LIB_AES.crypt_pack.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity FSM is
port (
    resetb_i : in std_logic ;
    clock_i : in std_logic ;
    end_key_expander_i : in std_logic ;
    start_i : in std_logic;
    enableMixcolumns_o : out std_logic;
    enableOutput_o : out std_logic;
    enableRoundcomputing_o: out std_logic;
    reset_key_expander_o: out std_logic;
    round_key_expander_o : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    start_key_expander_o : out std_logic;
    done_o : out std_logic );
end entity FSM ;

architecture FSM_arch of FSM is
-- definition du type enumere
type state is (idle , keyexpander , initialround , mainround , lastround, ENCoutput );
-- definition des signaux
signal etat_present , etat_futur : state := idle;
signal init_input :  std_logic;
signal count_output : bit4;
signal enable_input : std_logic;


component Counter
  port (enable_i           : in  std_logic;
      clock_i         : in  std_logic;
       reset_i         : in  std_logic;
        init_i         : in  std_logic;
        count_o           : out bit4);
end component;

begin -- moore_arch



DUT : Counter
port map(
        enable_i           => enable_input,
        clock_i         => clock_i,
        reset_i         => resetb_i,
        init_i         => init_input,
        count_o          => count_output
);  


seq_0 : process (clock_i , resetb_i )
    begin -- process seq_0
    if resetb_i = '0' then
        etat_present <= keyexpander ;
        elsif clock_i' event and clock_i = '1' then
        etat_present <= etat_futur ;
    end if;
end process seq_0 ;


    comb0 : process ( etat_present , start_i , end_key_expander_i ) is
    begin -- process comb0

        case etat_present is
        when idle =>
            if (start_i = '1') then
                etat_futur <= keyexpander ;
                else
                etat_futur <= idle ;
            end if;

        when keyexpander =>
            if end_key_expander_i = '1' then
                etat_futur <= initialround ;
                else
                etat_futur <= keyexpander ;
            end if;

        when initialround =>
            if (count_output = "0000") then --round0 : start round execution
                etat_futur <= initialround ;
                else if count_output > "0000" then
                etat_futur <= mainround;
                end if;
            end if;

        when mainround =>
            if count_output < "1010" then --round1 to round9 : rounds execution
                etat_futur <= mainround ;
                else if count_output ="1001" then
                etat_futur <= lastround ;
                end if;
            end if;

        when lastround =>
            if count_output < "1010" then --round10 : last round
                etat_futur <= lastround ;
                else if count_output ="1010" then
                etat_futur <= ENCoutput ;
                end if;
            end if;

        when ENCoutput =>
            if start_i = '0' then 
                etat_futur <= ENCoutput ;
                else
                etat_futur <= keyexpander ;
            end if;

end case ;
end process comb0 ;

-- Output logic of the VHDL MOORE FSM
comb1 : process ( etat_present )
begin -- proceenableMixcolumns_o : out std_logic;
case etat_present is
    when idle => --repos
        enableMixcolumns_o <= '0';
        enableOutput_o <='0';
        enableRoundcomputing_o <='0';
        reset_key_expander_o <='0';
        round_key_expander_o <=count_output;
        start_key_expander_o <='0';
        done_o <= '0';

    when keyexpander => --start key expander
        enableMixcolumns_o <= '0';
        enableOutput_o <='0';
        enableRoundcomputing_o <='0';
        reset_key_expander_o <='0';
        round_key_expander_o <= count_output;
        start_key_expander_o <='1';
        done_o <= '0';

    when initialround =>
        enableMixcolumns_o <= '0';
        enableOutput_o <='0';
        enableRoundcomputing_o <='1'; --1 for round0
        reset_key_expander_o <='0';
        round_key_expander_o <=count_output;
        start_key_expander_o <='0';
        done_o <= '0';

    when mainround =>
        enableMixcolumns_o <= '1';
        enableOutput_o <='0'; --not done
        enableRoundcomputing_o <='0'; --0 for round1-->round9
        reset_key_expander_o <='0';
        round_key_expander_o <=count_output; --start counting rounds
        start_key_expander_o <='0'; --done
        done_o <= '0';

    when lastround =>
        enableMixcolumns_o <= '0';
        enableOutput_o <='0'; --not done
        enableRoundcomputing_o <='0'; --0 for round10
        reset_key_expander_o <='0';
        round_key_expander_o <=count_output; --10 rounds 
        start_key_expander_o <='0'; --done
        done_o <= '0';

    when ENCoutput =>
        enableMixcolumns_o <= '0'; --no mixcolumn last round
        enableOutput_o <='1'; --done
        enableRoundcomputing_o <='0';
        reset_key_expander_o <='1';
        round_key_expander_o <=count_output; --reset counting
        start_key_expander_o <='0';
        done_o <= '1';

end case ;
end process comb1 ;
end architecture  FSM_arch;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library LIB_RTL ;
library LIB_AES;
use LIB_AES.crypt_pack.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Counter is
  port (enable_i           : in  std_logic;
        clock_i         : in  std_logic;
        reset_i         : in  std_logic;
        init_i         : in  std_logic;
        count_o           : out bit4);
end Counter;

architecture Counter_arch of Counter is
signal counter_s : bit4;

begin
count_o <= counter_s;
seq_0 : process (clock_i, reset_i,enable_i,init_i) is
begin -- process seq_0
if reset_i = '0' then -- asynchronous reset (active-low)
counter_s <= X"0";
elsif clock_i'event and clock_i = '1' then -- rising clock
if (enable_i = '1') then
if (init_i = '1') then
counter_s <= X"0";
else
counter_s <= counter_s + 1;
end if;
else
counter_s <= counter_s;
end if;
end if;
end process seq_0;

end Counter_arch;
```

The problem appears in the simulation, I'm having start_key_expander_o <='1'; which means it's in the state keyexpander! And enableRoundcomputing_o <='0'; is always 0 which means it's not entering in state: initialround!
I can't understand my mistake...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use ieee.numeric_std.all;
Use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
library LIB_RTL ;
library LIB_AES;
use LIB_AES.crypt_pack.all;



ENTITY FSM_tb IS
END FSM_tb;

ARCHITECTURE FSM_tb_arch OF FSM_tb IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Moore FSM

    COMPONENT FSM
port (
resetb_i : in std_logic ;
clock_i : in std_logic ;
end_key_expander_i : in std_logic ;
start_i : in std_logic;
enableMixcolumns_o : out std_logic;
enableOutput_o : out std_logic;
enableRoundcomputing_o: out std_logic;
reset_key_expander_o: out std_logic;
round_key_expander_o : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
start_key_expander_o : out std_logic;
done_o : out std_logic );
    END COMPONENT;

component Counter
  port (enable_i           : in  std_logic;
        clock_i         : in  std_logic;
        reset_i         : in  std_logic;
        init_i         : in  std_logic;
        count_o           : out bit4);
end component;


   --Inputs
   signal clock_input : std_logic := '0';
   signal resetb_input : std_logic := '1';
   signal end_key_expander_input : std_logic := '0';
   signal start_input : std_logic := '1';
   signal init_input :  std_logic :='0';
   signal enable_input : std_logic :='1';

  --Outputs
   signal enableMixcolumns_output : std_logic;
   signal enableOutput_output : std_logic := '0';
   signal enableRoundcomputing_output : std_logic := '0';
   signal reset_key_expander_output : std_logic := '0';
   signal round_key_expander_output : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";   
   signal start_key_expander_output : std_logic := '0';   
   signal done_output : std_logic := '0';   
   signal count_output : bit4;


BEGIN

-- Instantiate the Moore FSM 
uut: FSM PORT MAP (
            resetb_i                => resetb_input,
            clock_i                 => clock_input,
            end_key_expander_i      => end_key_expander_input,
            start_i                 => start_input,
            enableMixcolumns_o      => enableMixcolumns_output,
            enableOutput_o          => enableOutput_output,
            enableRoundcomputing_o  => enableRoundcomputing_output,
            reset_key_expander_o    => reset_key_expander_output,
            round_key_expander_o    => round_key_expander_output,
            start_key_expander_o    => start_key_expander_output,
            done_o                  => done_output
);

DUT : Counter
port map(
            enable_i        => enable_input,
            clock_i         => clock_input,
            reset_i         => resetb_input,
            init_i          => init_input,
            count_o         => count_output
);  

   -- Clock process definitions
clock_input <= not clock_input after 5 ns;
process
begin
     wait until clock_input = '1';
     resetb_input <= '0';
     wait;
end process;

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin  
   wait until clock_input = '1';



  -- e2
  end_key_expander_input <= '1' ;

    start_input <= '0';




  wait for 40 ns;
  -- fin 
  end_key_expander_input <= '0' ;
  enable_input <= '0';
  init_input <= '1';
  start_input <= '0';
  wait for 20 ns;
  done_output <='1';


      -- insert stimulus here 
      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: your comb0 process is missing `count_output` from the sensitivity list. Your testbench stimulus also doesnt align properly with the clock as you've used absolute time, much better to wait for clock edges. `for i in 1 to nclks loop wait until rising_edge(clk); end loop;`

Comment: so I put it like that?
   `stim_proc: process
   begin  
  for i in 1 to not clock_input loop
   wait until rising_edge(clock_input); 
   end loop;`

Comment: It doesn't accept to have an integer  1 to and std_logic type!

Comment: No, you wouldnt do that. You need to replace `wait for 40 ns;` with `for i in 1 to 4 loop wait until rising_edge(clock_input); end loop;`

Comment: Ok, I did like that.
But, still enable round computing is ='0' all the time!!

Comment: It's not even counting... the counter is always 0000

Comment: `enable_input` is always '0' in the testbench, and needs to be '1' in order for the counter to count.

Comment: I have initialized them already in the testbench `enable_input` = '1' and `init_input` ='0' `signal init_input :  std_logic :='0';
   signal enable_input : std_logic :='1';`

Comment: the counter without the FSM works normally... the problem is in the FSM

Comment: ok I found a small mistake in the reset, I've put `seq_0 : process (clock_i , resetb_i )
    begin -- process seq_0
    if resetb_i = '0' then
        etat_present <= keyexpander ;` so reset had to be 1 not 0! 
Now I find myself having Round enable Computing being 1... so entering in the next state, but count is always 0000

Comment: Ohhhh the same mistake in counter!!! nowit's counting....

Comment: You don't provide any necessary non-standard library packages (LIB_AES.crypt_pack, type mark bit4?) dis-allowing your problem from being duplicated. Provide a [mcve] in your question than your fixes in an answer. Exercise extreme care when providing two different arithmetic packages (numeric_std which you don't use and std_logic_unsigned, they rely on different declarations of types named unsigned. Your context clauses are full of 'dead wood'. Someone could consider the wrong polarity of reset as a typographical error.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm a new user here.. I just wanted to fix my problem because it's urgent. The crypt pack is a library for other constants … do I had to put it too?
Do u mean I have to repost my question like the minimal reproducible example?